# Integrate ReportPortal with Karate 0.9.4

Tags: karate, reportportal

I am looking for options to integrate ReportPortal with Karate 0.9.4 with Junit Runner. Does the current ReportPortal Agent support Karate 0.9.4 as it uses Cucumber Runner and possibly works with TestNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-karate

Else this is something you should take up with that team.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have tried something to integrate with reportportal from one of the contributors using ExecutionHook. Now, how do I add the class implementing ExecutionHook to the runner class. I was able to do this for Junit Run Listener by adding to reference RunNotifier which takes run RunListener object. But this one is of type ExecutionHook (Karate). Just want to understand if we have something available in karate runners. Appreciate your help. 

@karate

Comment: @VarunPatil refer this comment: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/970#issuecomment-557443551